# VS Express 2013 C# using "DA.Fill(DT);" and I keep getting An unhandled exception No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#

My code:

```
private void Fillcombo()
{
    OleDbConnection CS = new OleDbConnection();
    CS.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:ItemListdb.mdb;";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ItemList FROM ItemList", CS);
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    //        try
    {
        CS.Open();
        DA.Fill(DT);
        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cboItemList.Items.Add(DT.Rows[i]["ItemList"]);
        }
        CS.Close();
    }
}
```

When I created the dataset, I checked the connection, and it was successful.  But it appears my connection string is not making the connection because the fill data error indicates that it is null.  I've checked the internet over and over.  Watching video after video and trying their structure but no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You generally want to include the error message (i.e.  Stack trace) in your question when you're asking for help with debugging.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain you've read at least a large number of the many, many previous questions (and answers) here that contain that same error message. Right? Including the 10 that are shown on this very page, and that appeared as suggestions for you when you were typing your question? And none of those dozens of existing answers helped you? (And as an aside, it's a terrible idea to have a column that shares the name of your table, because when you read your code it's difficult to tell which one you're referencing.)

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionString appears to be incorrect :

```
CS.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:ItemListdb.mdb;";
```

The data source path is incorrect.  If the file is really in c:\, you want this connection string :

```
CS.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ItemListdb.mdb;";
```